# updating/Changing the value using button in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to update/change the `currentStatus` of a row from `0` to `1` using the `Approve` button in the datatable, but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone please help me?

[image]

This is how I store

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        $currentStatus = 0;

        $data = $request->validate([
            'to' => 'required',
            'date' => 'date',
            'address' => 'required',
            'reference' => 'required',
            'attention' => 'required',
            'area' => 'required',
            'project' => 'required',
            'salesman' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required'


        ]);
        \App\Contract::create($data + ['status' => $currentStatus]);
        return redirect('contracts/pendings');
    }
```

This is how I display in the datatables

```
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customers Name</th>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>Project Name</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            @forelse($pendingContracts as $pendingContract)
                            <td>{{$pendingContract->to}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pendingContract->date}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pendingContract->project}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"> 
                                    <a href="/contracts/pendings/{{$pendingContract->id}}" style="color: #ffffff;">View Details</a> 
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"> 
                                    <a href="" style="color: #ffffff;">Approve</a> 
                                </button>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        @empty
                        <center><p>no data</p></center>
                        @endforelse
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I share the sample code. Please check

*View file - Button*

```
<input data-id="{{$contract->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Approve" data-off="Disapprove" {{ $contract->is_approve ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Put the below JS code in the view file

```
<script>
$(document).off('change', '.toggle-class').on('change', '.toggle-class', function() {
    var url = 'contract/changestatus';
    var is_approve = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
    var contract_id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", 'is_approve': is_approve, 'contract_id': contract_id},
                success: function(data){
                console.log(data.success)
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

*Controller code*

```
public function changestatus(Request $request)
{
   $contract = Contract::find($request->contract_id);
   $contract->is_approve = $request->is_approve;
   $contract->save();
   return redirect()->route('admin.contract.index');
}
```

I hope this snippet is helpful to you. Thank you :)